# How do I add name and email to a Firebase user account during signup with phone number?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

In the Firebase docs it describes how to [create an account using phone number sign up](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth).

When signed in, Firebase returns a user object that looks like this:

[image]

However nowhere in the above docs does it describe how to add information like email and displayName during sign up.

How do I add this information to a profile during the user signup using phone number authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API provides no way of providing additional information at the moment an account is first created.  However, there are links at the bottom of that page that send you to information about how to [manage users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) after that.  In particular, you will want to read the section on [updating a user's profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile) and [setting a user's email address](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#set_a_users_email_address).  From the documentation:

```js
user.updateProfile({
  displayName: "Jane Q. User",
  photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
}).then(function() {
  // Update successful.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

And:

```js
user.updateEmail("user@example.com").then(function() {
  // Update successful.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```